# How to add an Insert row to a GridView which is databound to a SQL server table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm using C# ASP.NET 4 (VS2010) to create a database driven aspx file (SQL SERVER 2008 R2).

My aspx file containing a GridView which allows me to edit and delete rows from the SQL server's table.

I would like to add an insert row at the bottom of the Gridview, but I can't find the control for that, even after searching the internet for hours.

When using Microsoft SQL Server Management studio there is a way to edit the top 200 rows of a table in a nice gridview, and there is an insert row at the bottom.
My GridView is pure aspx with no code behind.

I would like to imitate the that insertion row.

This is how the edit (with the insert row) looks on Microsoft SQL Server Management studio:

[image]

See at the picture above how I'm inserting the 3rd row of the table.
See that there is a new row for insertion at the bottom of the gridview.

Is it possible that there is no control for that with aspx gridview?

If there isn't automatic insert row control, how do I do that with minimal C# code?

With no solution, I thought of adding a button at under the GridView which will add a new empty row to the table. The problem is, my table do not allow nulls :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992091/how-to-make-an-insert-row-with-asp-net-3-5-gridview

Comment: Thanks sisdog, found that myself. Isn't there anything built in nowadays?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure that you include an "InsertCommand" in your SqlDataSource and you'll need to do a little bit of work in the code-behind.  To get a nice overview check out the article on this topic at the [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18165/Using-the-Insert-feature-of-SqlDataSource-with-Gri)